# What is the convention for topic name parameterization?

Tags: ros, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a convention or "best practice" for making topic names configurable?

I can think of two obvious ways to do it, but would like to use the "standard".

1. Name the topics statically and force people to remap as they see fit.
2. Make the topic names ROS parameters

While the difference may seem trivial, developing consistent conventions eases and speeds development, and I'd like to go with the convention if there is one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9849/what-is-the-convention-for-topic-name-parameterization?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-29

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Topic names can be remapped when you start a node, there is no need for a parameter to be explicitly declared in your program. For instance, if my node subscribes to "my_topic" , and you have a node that publishes "your_topic", you could still use my code by remapping the name:

```
 rosrun my_package my_node my_topic:=your_topic
```

More information on namespaces and remapping can be found on the wiki: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments

You can also remap topics using launch files using roslaunch's "remap" tag (http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/remap).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-08-27**:
@fergs can we do the other way round? i.e. can the publisher change its published topic name? if so can you please show the code like above? thanks